# Google+ - How to open the interactive post dialog without a button click?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, interactive

Is there a way to open the [Google+ interactive post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) dialog without the need of clicking the button first? 
I would like to have it displayed in a website directly.

Below is the related code from the G+ examples.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button
      class="g-interactivepost"
      data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
      data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
      data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
      data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
      data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
      data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
      Tell your friends
    </button>
```

Comment: What happens if you simulate a click on it?

Comment: Facing same problem , Please give some solution, below answer is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to that button element (You can possibly use a different element entirely as long as you include all the supplied attributes -- can't be sure without testing) and style it to be hidden. 
From there, just trigger a click on it on whatever event you want.

I.E. 
HTML:

```
<button
  id="thisdumbbutton"
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
  data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
  data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
  data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
  data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
  Tell your friends
</button>
```

CSS:

```
#thisdumbbutton{ display: none; }
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);

   $('#something').hover(function(){
      $('#thisdumbbutton').click();
   });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, the ID isn't really necessary, but you might want to include multiple of these on a page or something, so I think it's more forward-compatible. If you end up needing n elements, you'll want to use the relations between the element triggering the event and the button(or whatver) element. i.e. `$('#thing').hover(function(){$(this).prev().parent().next().children('.thisisaweirdexample').click();});`

Comment: I tried your example and the G+ Share box isn't showing up. Did I miss something?